# Is there any reverse of explode in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame below

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
3  2  1
4  2  2
```

Is there any reverse of explode function

```
   A       B
0  1  [1, 2]
1  2  [1, 2]
```

Comment: groupby + agg(list)